# How to view FsImage/Edit Logs file in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm Beginner in Hadoop. I wanted to view fs-image and Edit logs in hadoop. I have searched it in many blogs, nothing is clear. Please can any one tell me step by step procedure to view the Edit log/fs-image file in hadoop.

My version: Apache Hadoop: **Hadoop-1.2.1**

My Installed director is **![/home/students/hadoop-1.2.1]**

I'm listing steps what i have tried based on some blogs.

Ex.1. **$ hdfs dfsadmin -fetchImage /tmp**

Ex.2. **hdfs oiv -i /tmp/fsimage_0000000000000001386 -o /tmp/fsimage.txt**

Nothing works for me.

It shows that **hdfs is not a directory or a file.**

Answer (score 1):

For edit log, navigate to

```
/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name/current
```

then;

```
ls -l
```

to view the complete name of the log file you want to extract; after then

```
hdfs oev -i editFileName -o /home/youraccount/Desktop/edits_your.xml -p XML
```

For the fsimage;

```
hdfs oiv -i fsimage -o /home/youraccount/Desktop/fsimage_your.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the bin directory and try to execute the same commands